# Navigating menu with both keyboard and mouse issue

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I have a sound effect that plays when the user hovers over a button with the mouse. The same sound effect also plays when the user uses the keyboard to navigate through the menu buttons and this is triggered when the button is selected.

I have a separate sound effect that plays when the user actually clicks / activates the button.

[image]

Let's say the user moves the mouse over a button, it will play the onmouseenter sound correctly. Next we click the button, however since clicking both triggers the onclick trigger AS WELL AS the select trigger, we hear 2 sounds. I only want to hear the onclick sound in this case. I need the select event trigger to cater for keyboard users so I can't simply delete it.

I have about 100 buttons like this so would prefer something that wouldn't involve changing the inspector since then I'd need to do that 100 times. It would be preferable to just be able to change something in the script. However if that's not possible open to ideas of changing the inspector.

Any advice appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I haven't got an immediate answer for you, but if your answer does involve "changing the inspector" you could consider setting up a prefab with your desired button setup and using variants to perform changes on top to save some work duplicating those kinds of changes across your project.

Comment: If you'd like a C# based answer, it would help to include what c# you already have to reproduce the problem. See [mre] for more info.